# Порядок перемнных в структуре Go golang

Tags: golang, struct

Мы занем, что в си порядок переменных влияет на размер структуры, и иногда(хоть и изредка) это оказывается важным. [Пример](https://%3Cscript%20src=%22//onlinegdb.com/embed/js/XpwxxxSra?theme=dark%22%3E%3C/script%3E):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct s1{
    char a;
    int b;
    char c;
    int d;
};

struct s2{
    char a;
    char c;
    int b;
    int d;
};


int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    printf("\n %ld",sizeof(struct s1));
    printf("\n %ld",sizeof(struct s2));

    return 0;
}
```

результат выполнения кода выше:

```
Hello World
 16
 12

...Program finished with exit code 0
Press ENTER to exit console.
```

Мы знаем, что это происходит по причине выравнивания памяти операционной системой. И более  того, [последствия](https://habr.com/ru/articles/756074/) этого мы можем наблюдать в другом софте, например postgresql. Внимание вопрос: есть ли в go такая же особенность?

Comment: Из разговоров [тут](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/tfdi5u/go_struct_memory_layout/) и [тут](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/10014) я так понял, что спецификация не гарантирует никакой конкретный memory layout, но на данный момент Go ведёт себя как C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Про выравнивание спецификация Go [почти ничего не говорит](https://go.dev/ref/spec#System_considerations)

Но можно посмотреть, как вычисляется выравнивание полей внутри структуры, [в исходниках пакета `reflect`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.1:src/reflect/type.go;drc=be4fe08b57b3365f3f5db2e2def296904557442d;l=2153).
Дескриптор структуры собирается из дескрипторов полей поле за полем. Смещение очередного поля структуры [вычисляется](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.1:src/reflect/type.go;drc=be4fe08b57b3365f3f5db2e2def296904557442d;l=2354) так:

```
        offset := align(size, uintptr(ft.Align_))
        if offset < size {
            panic("reflect.StructOf: struct size would exceed virtual address space")
        }
        if ft.Align_ > typalign {
            typalign = ft.Align_
        }
        size = offset + ft.Size_
        if size < offset {
            panic("reflect.StructOf: struct size would exceed virtual address space")
        }
        f.Offset = offset
```

Здесь `ft` - дескриптор добавляемого поля, `size` - текущий размер структуры, `ft.Align_` - требования к выравниванию типа поля `ft`, `typalign` - выравнивание структуры.

Функция [`reflect.align`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/master:src/reflect/value.go;drc=c700c23cef4b6501c0ccce248db57e30683eea99;l=941)

```
// align returns the result of rounding x up to a multiple of n.
// n must be a power of two.
func align(x, n uintptr) uintptr {
    return (x + n - 1) &^ (n - 1)
}
```

Эта функция предполагает, что выравнивание `n` - степень двойки. Функция возвращает кратное `n` из интервала `[x, x+n)`. То есть `go` размещает поля структур в соответстввии с гарантиями выравнивания для типов полей.

Так как это внутренняя функция, нельзя рассматривать этот алгоритм выравнивания полей как гарантию. В следующей реализации они могут поменять.

Экспериментально можно узнать выравнивания полей через функции из пакетов `reflect` или `unsafe`.

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type S1 struct {
    A int8
    B int32
    C int8
    D int32
}

type S2 struct {
    A int8
    C int8
    B int32
    D int32
}

func main() {
    t1 := reflect.TypeOf(S1{})
    PrintStruct(t1)

    t2 := reflect.TypeOf(S2{})
    PrintStruct(t2)
}

func PrintStruct(typ reflect.Type) {
    fmt.Println(typ.Name())
    fmt.Println("size ", typ.Size())
    for i, fld := range reflect.VisibleFields(typ) {
        fmt.Printf("%d: %s %v: offset %d\n", i, fld.Name, fld.Type, fld.Offset)
    }
}
```

[Результат](https://go.dev/play/p/tqx-HwSU7LU):

```
S1
size  16
0: A int8: offset 0
1: B int32: offset 4
2: C int8: offset 8
3: D int32: offset 12
S2
size  12
0: A int8: offset 0
1: C int8: offset 1
2: B int32: offset 4
3: D int32: offset 8
```